# Change random jquery background color to repeating sequential?

Tags: jquery, css

Currently assigning random background colors using the following code:

```
 // Add random background color to tiles
 var colors = ["#F2B036","#10AF70","#2A82AF","#68B0BB", "#6B7889"];
 var rand = function() {
                return Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
            };
 var randomColor = function() {
                    var x = colors[rand()];
                    return x;
            };

 $(".ThumbnailMenuItem").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", randomColor());
 });
```

However I don't want this to be random because the colors will sometimes appear right next to each other.

How can I adjust this so that it uses the colors in the array sequentially but starts over at position zero if there are more ThumbnailMenuItem classes than colors in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a counter and update it.

```
var i = 0;
$(".ThumbnailMenuItem").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[i++]); // increment here
    if(i == 5) i = 0; // reset the counter here
});
```

Comment: Will `$(this).css("background-color", colors[i++]);` begin at `colors[1]` , instead of `colors[0]` ?

Comment: @guest271314 no. It will begin at `0` since I've used post fix increment operator. `colors[i++]` at first will be `colors[0]` but when evaluating the condition, it will be `1`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```js
 var colors = ["#F2B036","#10AF70","#2A82AF","#68B0BB", "#6B7889"];

// iterating over each of the elements returned by the selector,
// with the css() method, using the first argument (the index
// of the current element in the collection) of the anonymous function:
$(".ThumbnailMenuItem").css("background-color", function (index) {
  // returning the modulus of the index against the length
  // of the array of colours:
  return colors[index%colors.length];
});
```

```css
li {
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
  <li class="ThumbnailMenuItem"></li>
</ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [modulo (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder).
- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).